# Group by in Unix

Tags: unix, awk

I have a text file (sample.txt) and below is the structure:

```
CODE| NAME| CITY |AGE
01 | BEN| NYC| 40
01| GLEN| SYDNEY|40
03|MARK| TORONTO| 30
```

I want to filter out the records based on column values in Unix. Below is the command I wrote.
Is it correct? I am not sure :/

```
awk -F "|" '{ if ($1 == "01" &&  $3== "40") print  }' sample.txt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it looks correct to me except the condition part. I think you meant to check 
`if ($1 == "01" && $4 == "40")`. Give it a try and see how it goes.

```
awk -F "|" '{ if ($1 == "01" && $4== "40") print }' sample.txt
```

Comment: I did some R&D and found the more appropriate would be below lines:    awk -F "|" '{ if ($1 == "01" && $4== "40\r") print }' sample.txt